# How to make the X-axis time dynamically refresh by using pyqtgraph TimeAxisItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm going to make a real-time curve out of a sequence of data. First, I established a quantity dictionary, which has 3 groups of data. The current program can draw a curve dynamically. The X-axis can also show the time, which is also updated in real time. However, the time at different points in the X-axis is always the same value.

```
UNIX_EPOCH_naive = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0) #offset-naive datetime
UNIX_EPOCH_offset_aware = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo = pytz.utc) #offset-aware datetime
UNIX_EPOCH = UNIX_EPOCH_naive

TS_MULT_us = 1e6

def now_timestamp(ts_mult=TS_MULT_us, epoch=UNIX_EPOCH):
    return(int((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds()*ts_mult))

def int2dt(ts, ts_mult=TS_MULT_us):
    tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
    user_ts = int(time.time())
    d1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(user_ts))
    d1x = tz.localize(d1)
    return(d1x)

def dt2int(dt, ts_mult=TS_MULT_us, epoch=UNIX_EPOCH):
    delta = dt - epoch
    return(int(delta.total_seconds()*ts_mult))

def td2int(td, ts_mult=TS_MULT_us):
    return(int(td.total_seconds()*ts_mult))

def int2td(ts, ts_mult=TS_MULT_us):
    return(datetime.timedelta(seconds=float(ts)/ts_mult))

class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeAxisItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [int2dt(value).strftime("%H:%M:%S") for value in values]

p = win.addPlot(title="Data-Time Graph", axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})
data_dict = {}
p.addLegend() 
data_x=[]


def getDate():
    ......
    .....
    curve = p.plot(pen = color[len(data_dict)],name=name)
    data_dict[name] = [curve] # dictionary: {key:[curve,[dadta1,data2,...]]}
    data_dict[name].append([val])

def addToDisplay():
    p.plot()
    for i in data_dict.items():
        data = i[1][1] #
        curve = i[1][0] #
        if(len(data) > data_frequency):#
             data_y=data[- data_frequency:]
        else:
             data_y = data[:]
        curve.setData(data_y)#

if __name__ == "__main__":
    th= threading.Thread(target=getDate)# 
    th.start()
    timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(addToDisplay) 
    timer.start(10)
```

What I hope is that the X-axis is dynamically refreshed, with the latest time on the right side and the past time is on the left side.

Comment: can you please help me [Help Please in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67343848/implement-cross-hair-in-custom-pyqtgraph-plot-widget-like-in-the-pyqtgraph-stock)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve since your code doesn't run but it seems you're trying to create a timestamp plot. Here's a widget that uses `TimeAxisItem` to keep track of elapsed time on the X-axis.

**PyQt5**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import time

"""Scrolling Timestamp Plot Widget Example"""

class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    """Internal timestamp for x-axis"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeAxisItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        """Function overloading the weak default version to provide timestamp"""

        return [QtCore.QTime().currentTime().addMSecs(value).toString('mm:ss') for value in values]

class ScrollingTimestampPlot(QtGui.QWidget):
    """Scrolling plot widget with timestamp on x-axis and dynamic y-axis"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScrollingTimestampPlot, self).__init__(parent)

        # Internal timestamp for x-axis
        self.timestamp = QtCore.QTime()
        self.timestamp.start()

        # Desired Frequency (Hz) = 1 / self.FREQUENCY
        # USE FOR TIME.SLEEP (s)
        self.FREQUENCY = 0.025

        # Screen refresh rate to update plot (ms)
        # self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE = 1 / Desired Frequency (Hz) * 1000
        # USE FOR TIMER.TIMER (ms)
        self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE = self.FREQUENCY * 1000

        self.DATA_POINTS_TO_DISPLAY = 200

        # Automatically pops from left if length is full
        self.data = deque(maxlen=self.DATA_POINTS_TO_DISPLAY)

        # Create Plot Widget 
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})

        # Enable/disable plot squeeze (Fixed axis movement)
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.plotItem.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setTitle('Scrolling Timestamp Plot Example')
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setLabel('left', 'Value')
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'Time (s)')

        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot = self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.plot()
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot.setPen(246,212,255)

        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget)

        self.read_position_thread()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        """Update plot"""

        self.position_update_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.position_update_timer.timeout.connect(self.plot_updater)
        self.position_update_timer.start(self.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_refresh_rate())

    def read_position_thread(self):
        """Read in data using a thread"""

        self.current_position_value = 0
        self.position_update_thread = Thread(target=self.read_position, args=())
        self.position_update_thread.daemon = True
        self.position_update_thread.start()

    def read_position(self):
        frequency = self.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_frequency()
        while True:
            self.current_position_value = random.randint(1,101) 
            time.sleep(frequency)

    def plot_updater(self):
        self.data_point = float(self.current_position_value)

        self.data.append({'x': self.timestamp.elapsed(), 'y': self.data_point})
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot.setData(x=[item['x'] for item in self.data], y=[item['y'] for item in self.data])

    def clear_scrolling_timestamp_plot(self):
        self.data.clear()

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_frequency(self):
        return self.FREQUENCY

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_refresh_rate(self):
        return self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_layout(self):
        return self.layout

    def get_current_position_value(self):
        return self.current_position_value

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget(self):
        return self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget

# Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create main application window
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    mw.setWindowTitle('Scrolling Plot Example')

    # Create scrolling plot
    scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget = ScrollingTimestampPlot()

    # Create and set widget layout
    # Main widget container
    cw = QtGui.QWidget()
    ml = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    cw.setLayout(ml)
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)

    # Can use either to add plot to main layout
    #ml.addWidget(scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget(),0,0)
    ml.addLayout(scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_layout(),0,0)
    mw.show()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

**PyQt4**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import time

"""Scrolling Timestamp Plot Widget Example"""

class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    """Internal timestamp for x-axis"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeAxisItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        """Function overloading the weak default version to provide timestamp"""

        return [QtCore.QTime().addMSecs(value).toString('mm:ss') for value in values]

class ScrollingTimestampPlot(QtGui.QWidget):
    """Scrolling plot widget with timestamp on x-axis and dynamic y-axis"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScrollingTimestampPlot, self).__init__(parent)

        # Internal timestamp for x-axis
        self.timestamp = QtCore.QTime()
        self.timestamp.start()

        # Desired Frequency (Hz) = 1 / self.FREQUENCY
        # USE FOR TIME.SLEEP (s)
        self.FREQUENCY = 0.025

        # Screen refresh rate to update plot (ms)
        # self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE = 1 / Desired Frequency (Hz) * 1000
        # USE FOR TIMER.TIMER (ms)
        self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE = self.FREQUENCY * 1000

        self.DATA_POINTS_TO_DISPLAY = 200

        # Automatically pops from left if length is full
        self.data = deque(maxlen=self.DATA_POINTS_TO_DISPLAY)

        # Create Plot Widget 
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})

        # Enable/disable plot squeeze (Fixed axis movement)
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.plotItem.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setTitle('Scrolling Timestamp Plot Example')
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setLabel('left', 'Value')
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'Time (s)')

        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot = self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.plot()
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot.setPen(246,212,255)

        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget)

        self.read_position_thread()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        """Update plot"""

        self.position_update_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.position_update_timer.timeout.connect(self.plot_updater)
        self.position_update_timer.start(self.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_refresh_rate())

    def read_position_thread(self):
        """Read in data using a thread"""

        self.current_position_value = 0
        self.position_update_thread = Thread(target=self.read_position, args=())
        self.position_update_thread.daemon = True
        self.position_update_thread.start()

    def read_position(self):
        frequency = self.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_frequency()
        while True:
            self.current_position_value = random.randint(1,101) 
            time.sleep(frequency)

    def plot_updater(self):
        self.data_point = float(self.current_position_value)

        self.data.append({'x': self.timestamp.elapsed(), 'y': self.data_point})
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot.setData(x=[item['x'] for item in self.data], y=[item['y'] for item in self.data])

    def clear_scrolling_timestamp_plot(self):
        self.data.clear()

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_frequency(self):
        return self.FREQUENCY

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_refresh_rate(self):
        return self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_layout(self):
        return self.layout

    def get_current_position_value(self):
        return self.current_position_value

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget(self):
        return self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget

# Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create main application window
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    mw.setWindowTitle('Scrolling Plot Example')

    # Create scrolling plot
    scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget = ScrollingTimestampPlot()

    # Create and set widget layout
    # Main widget container
    cw = QtGui.QWidget()
    ml = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    cw.setLayout(ml)
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)

    # Can use either to add plot to main layout
    #ml.addWidget(scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget(),0,0)
    ml.addLayout(scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_layout(),0,0)
    mw.show()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: This is a very good example, thanks , Nathancy. I run this code and it can plot the curve, but, the X-axis did not show the time label.

Comment: What do you mean by the time label? It should be showing `minute:seconds` as the X-axis label like in the .gif or are you looking for a different timestamp format?

Comment: The X-axis is only a line with scale, but  there is no any digital chars  like your gif  shown ,"mm:ss", I installed PyQT5, python 3.6. Thanks, Nathancy.

Comment: I added the PyQt5 version. To change the timestamp format you can look at the format parameters [here](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtime.html#toString) and [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/datetime/)

Comment: Hi,Nathancy，yes, this PyQt5 code works well, and inspired me. Many thanks for your great help.

Comment: Further it is strongly recommended to not use Python Threads within a QApplication you should use QThread instead but for simplicity in this case you could have probably gotten away with just using QTimer to call the read functionality

Comment: When I run the PyQt5 version, it scrolls fine but the timestamp axis labels keep changing. Here is  an [example](https://imgur.com/c51mCFK). I'm using Python 3.6, macOS 11.3.2.

Comment: For the PyQt5 version, I believe "QtCore.QTime().currentTime()" should be "QtCore.QTime(0, 0)"

Answer (score -1):

I have left his comments in the code to indicate the changes made (`QtGui.QWidget` to `QtWidgets.QWidget` & being more precise about specifying INT variables).

This was the final code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import time

"""Scrolling Timestamp Plot Widget Example"""


class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    """Internal timestamp for x-axis"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeAxisItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        """Function overloading the weak default version to provide timestamp"""
        # Convert values to integers before using them in addMSecs
        return [QtCore.QTime(0,0).addMSecs(int(value)).toString('mm:ss') for value in values]


class ScrollingTimestampPlot(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """Scrolling plot widget with timestamp on x-axis and dynamic y-axis"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScrollingTimestampPlot, self).__init__(parent)

        # Internal timestamp for x-axis
        self.timestamp = QtCore.QTime()
        self.timestamp.start()

        # Desired Frequency (Hz) = 1 / self.FREQUENCY
        # USE FOR TIME.SLEEP (s)
        self.FREQUENCY = 0.025

        # Screen refresh rate to update plot (ms)
        # self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE = 1 / Desired Frequency (Hz) * 1000
        # USE FOR TIMER.TIMER (ms)
        self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE = self.FREQUENCY * 1000

        self.DATA_POINTS_TO_DISPLAY = 200

        # Automatically pops from left if length is full
        self.data = deque(maxlen=self.DATA_POINTS_TO_DISPLAY)

        # Create Plot Widget
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})

        # Enable/disable plot squeeze (Fixed axis movement)
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.plotItem.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setTitle('Scrolling Timestamp Plot Example')
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setLabel('left', 'Value')
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'Time (s)')

        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot = self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.plot()
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot.setPen(246, 212, 255)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget)

        self.read_position_thread()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        """Update plot"""

        self.position_update_timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.position_update_timer.timeout.connect(self.plot_updater)
        self.position_update_timer.start(self.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_refresh_rate())

    def read_position_thread(self):
        """Read in data using a thread"""

        self.current_position_value = 0
        self.position_update_thread = Thread(target=self.read_position, args=())
        self.position_update_thread.daemon = True
        self.position_update_thread.start()

    def read_position(self):
        frequency = self.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_frequency()
        while True:
            self.current_position_value = random.randint(1, 101)
            time.sleep(frequency)

    def plot_updater(self):
        self.data_point = float(self.current_position_value)

        self.data.append({'x': self.timestamp.elapsed(), 'y': self.data_point})
        self.scrolling_timestamp_plot.setData(x=[item['x'] for item in self.data], y=[item['y'] for item in self.data])

    def clear_scrolling_timestamp_plot(self):
        self.data.clear()

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_frequency(self):
        return self.FREQUENCY

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_refresh_rate(self):
        return int(self.SCROLLING_TIMESTAMP_PLOT_REFRESH_RATE)

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_layout(self):
        return self.layout

    def get_current_position_value(self):
        return self.current_position_value

    def get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget(self):
        return self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget


# Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create main application window
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    mw = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()  # Change to QtWidgets.QMainWindow
    mw.setWindowTitle('Scrolling Plot Example')

    # Create scrolling plot
    scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget = ScrollingTimestampPlot()

    # Create and set widget layout
    # Main widget container
    cw = QtWidgets.QWidget()  # Change to QtWidgets.QWidget
    ml = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()  # QGridLayout is actually from QtWidgets, not QtGui
    cw.setLayout(ml)
    mw.setCentralWidget(cw)

    # Can use either to add plot to main layout
    # ml.addWidget(scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget(),0,0)
    ml.addLayout(scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.get_scrolling_timestamp_plot_layout(), 0, 0)
    mw.show()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().exec_()  # Use QtWidgets.QApplication here
```